# Can I serialize byte array in java?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a method where I am receiving input stream, I need to decrypt that data first then
serialize that data. But my data is not getting serialize. My file is a hash file. 
Please help me. My code is -

```
private byte[] getSerializeEncryptedBytes(InputStream inputStream,String password)
               throws Exception {
byte[] fileBytes = getByteArrayFromInputStream(inputStream);
fileBytes = AESEncrytion.getDecryptedData(fileBytes, password);
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = objectInputStream = new 
               ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
Object dataObject = objectInputStream.readObject();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
out.writeObject(fileBytes);
out.flush();
byte[] serializeByte = bos.toByteArray();
out.close();
Util.writeFileNewWay(new File("soapSerialized.txt"), serializeByte);
```

This is my second method -

```
public byte[] getByteArrayFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws 
              IOException {
 ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 int nRead;
 byte[] data = new byte[16384];
 while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
 }
 buffer.flush();
 return buffer.toByteArray();
```

}

Can I serialize byte array ?

Comment: Why do you say your data isn't serialized? What does this code do?

Comment: I am receiving a file in input stream, it is encrypted. I need to decrypt it and then serialize its data and write in a file. @kevin

Comment: of course u can serialize byte[] as JVM creates object of that byte array , and objects can be serialize.

Comment: Why are you reading are you reading and writing to Object streams in this case?  Which object is involved because it doesn't appear you have one. It appears you have a byte[] containing text.

Comment: Also why not decrypt and copy the data as you read it...

Comment: I am receiving data through input stream, I cant change it, I have to write that data in serialize file, I am receiving a file which contains data in hash table format. @Peter.

Comment: Ok, by why write it as an Object Stream and give it a `.txt` file extension.  BTW Soap is usually XML, I am confused why Object Stream is being used at all other than to confuse matters.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question:

> Can I serialize byte array ?

Actually is "you don't need to do so".  Your code apparently writes bytes to disk, and then reads bytes from disk; everything transparent, you are doing pretty nice.

Does your code produce any error?

Comment: I am getting following exception -java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0D0A2020 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:782) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)

Comment: I am sorry, I hadn't noticed you were using `ObjectInputStream`.  I suggest you drop that and try using only `FileInputStream` since you only need to write, read and handle byte arrays